# PHP : echo wordpress comments link and comments number on a href

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried the search but did not get the complete answer to my question.
I build a WordPress website with redux framework options panel and need switch on/off the option to hide meta info on WordPress posts.

I got already post date&author post link working but have a problem with echo href on WordPress comments link.

original code looks like this

```
<i class="far fa-comment"></i>&nbsp;<a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number('No comments', '1 comment', '% comments'); ?></a>
```

but I need to echo it inside PHP code

```
<?php global $wpdf;
if( $wpdf['text-muted']){
    //Do Something if switch is on(i.e - true)
    if(esc_html($wpdf['text-muted'] == '1')) { 
        echo '<i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>&nbsp;';
        echo wpdf_post_date();
        echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;<i class="far fa-user"></i>&nbsp;';
        echo the_author_posts_link();
        echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;<i class="far fa-comment"></i>&nbsp;';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
echo '<i class="far fa-comment"></i>&nbsp;<a href="'.get_comments_link( $post_ID ).'">'.comments_number("No comments", "1 comment", "% comments").'</a>';
```

Comment: works,but now i have like this:   March 26, 2018 (updated April 11, 2018) |  wpdf |  http://localhost/wpdf/phasellus-varius-sem-nec-massa-pretium-maximus/#respondNo comments,it displays comment link itself only,but not working as a link.

Comment: There were single quotes I fixed now to try.

Comment: still displays only link itself,see here: https://www.upload.ee/image/8322235/WPDF___WordPress_Design_Framework.png

Comment: I have updated the code and now you have to pass the post id in comment get function.

Comment: still not working as a link to comment itself,here is what i got now:https://www.upload.ee/image/8322280/WPDF___WordPress_Design_Framework.png

Comment: fixed it: echo '<a href="'.comments_popup_link(__('No comments', 'wpdf'), '1', '%').'"></a>';